# Why is there no Share option when the Wordpress AutoSocial plugin posts to the fan page?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, share, auto-update

When posts auto-update to my Facebook fan page via the WP-Autosocial plugin, why is there an option to Like and an option to Comment, but no option to Share?  Anything posted manually to the page has all three options, but autoupdates from WP-Autosocial are missing Share.